# CodeIgniter: how to change URL name in a multilingual website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question regarding the URLs of a website developed with CodeIgniter which offers content in two different languages: **en** and **de**

I would like to create SEO friendly URLs for both languages.

My question:

How can I change following URL

**www.mysite.com/en/landscape**

in

**www.mysiste.com/de/landschaft**

for German?

Comment: check this [link](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n) for complete solution

Comment: He wants to reroute controller/method names not only the language segment.

Comment: Yes, excatly. I can how do it? Reroute controller/method names...

Comment: are your language files stored in a database?

Comment: also to considerate: are the links en/landscape and de/landschaft created by user input (like our SO site questions), is it created by your own backend or are you managing a few hardcoded pages only?

Comment: Hi, the page en/landscape is created by a function landscape in the index controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the codeigniter language library with this class extension: [URI Language Identifier](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier). I also use this controller for switching the language

```
class LangSwitch extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();      
}
public function switchLanguage($language = "") {

    $this->load->library('user_agent');
    $referrer = $this->agent->referrer();

    $l = substr($referrer, strlen(base_url()));

    if(isset($referrer)){
        preg_match('/\/(.+)$/i',$l,$match);
        $redirect_url;
        if (empty($match)) {
            redirect(base_url().$language ,'refresh');
        }
        else{
            $redirect_url = base_url().$language.$match[1];
        }
        redirect($redirect,'refresh');
    }else{
        redirect(base_url(),'refresh');
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.